# ffmpeg converted mp4 files won't play on videojs

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert an hls source to mp4 but the ouputted file won't play on any internet video players. Currently I am using videojs

here is how I am converting it.

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://mnmedias.api.telequebec.tv/m3u8/29880.m3u8" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -movflags +faststart ./public/videos/cut-videos/knife/parlet.mp4
```

the video player is outputting this:

video.js:498 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: It seems to be an intermitant issue